# How to extend a list from a method of inherited class

Tags: python, list, oop, inheritance

I have two classes: BaseClass and Antifraud, which is derived from BaseClass. There is a method in BaseClass that have a list, like this:

```
class BaseClass:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def create_metrics(self):
        self.metrics_list = ['score',
                             'precision',
                             'recall']
```

I want that when I instantiate the class Antifraud, the list `self.metrics_list` will be the same as before plus `'f1'`. I have tried the following:

```
class Antifraud(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.metrics_list.extend(['f1'])

a = Antifraud()
```

But I get the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Antifraud' object has no attribute 'metrics_list'
```

How could I solve my issue? Is it even possible to achieve? Thanks

Comment: You didn't call `create_metrics`

Comment: You never called super.create_metrics()

Comment: Do I have to call super for every method that is in the BaseClass?

Comment: you may want to add `self.create_metrics()` into  the init on your base class

Comment: you do not have to call super every time, only when you have the same name in multiple classes (like `__init__`)

Comment: `Do I have to call super for every method` - No. Just the ones that you need. In this case `self.metrics_list` doesn't exist at this point - base class's init doesn't create it, you didn't create it manually, so you need to call the base class method to create it, and only then you can extend it.

Answer (score 1):

you can call the `create_metrics` method before to extend `self.metrics_list`, by calling first `create_metrics` you are creating `self.metrics_list`:

```
class Antifraud(BaseClass):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.create_metrics()
        self.metrics_list.extend(['f1'])
print(Antifraud().metrics_list)
```

output:

```
['score', 'precision', 'recall', 'f1']
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be considered a bad practice to not initialize instance's attributes outside of `__init__`

You can update your `BaseClass` to

```
    class BaseClass:
        def __init__(self):
            self.metrics_list = ['score', 'precision', 'recall']
```

and then your `AntiFraud` class will work.